# Enable scroll bounce on horizontal scroll in a mobile website

Tags: html, iphone, scroll, web, bounce

I'm developing a website where I have `overflow-x: scroll;` and `overflow-y: hidden;` for a certain div on the page. All of that works correctly, but I was wondering if it's possible to enable the bounce effect when scrolling horizontally on a mobile device (namely iPhone as that is my only means of testing right this moment).

The effect works when scrolling the entire page vertically but not horizontally within that div. If it matters, I have a meta tag that restricts the window scale to 1x, which shouldn't theoretically be an issue.

EDIT: To explain further -- the scrolling is very static and doesn't continue when you lift your finger off the screen.